# How to create retina image from JPEG with PHP

Tags: php, png, jpeg, retina

A few months ago i wrote the following script to convert an uploaded image with `PHP to Retina` and `non` retina images. The iphone app that was working with this script only used PNG images, so i wrote the script to work with PNG's.

```
$filename = dirname(__FILE__)."/uploads/" . $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
$filename = str_replace('.png', '_retina.png', $filename);
file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name']));

$image_info = getimagesize($filename);
$image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$new_width = $width/2.0;
$new_height = $height/2.0;

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

imagealphablending($new_image, false);
imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
$color = imagecolortransparent($new_image, imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $color);

imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

$new_filename = str_replace('_retina.png', '.png', $filename);

imagepng($new_image, $new_filename);
```

Now i need the same script but then to be used with Jpeg images. Because the iphone app will load images with a higher resolution we chose Jpeg. But i can't figure out how to make that work.

**What i've tried so far:**

- Replacing `imagecreatefrompng` with the jpeg version
- Replacing `imagepng` with the jpeg version

Does anybody have a working example or useful link that can set me to the right direction?

Comment: I'd just use `imagejpeg` if there is no transparency.

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov ah wait, offcourse its a Jpeg and im using transparency commands, thats whats failing right?

Comment: I think that if you create it from png, you still can work with transparency. It will just gray out (I think) when you'll call imagejpeg at the end to save it.

Comment: Is the image still coming in as a png or is it coming in as a jpg?

Comment: @Pitchinnate no its uploaded as JPG.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so what are they?

Comment: @Pitchinnate just figured out my problem, i will post he answer below so others can learn from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was about. I assumed jpg php functions could not handle the transparency, so i removed those lines and forgot about them. Apparently it just creates a white background and it does not fail. So the script is as follows:

```
$filename = dirname(__FILE__)."/uploads/" . $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
$filename = str_replace('.jpg', '_retina.jpg', $filename);
file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name']));

$image_info = getimagesize($filename);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$new_width = $width/2.0;
$new_height = $height/2.0;

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

imagealphablending($new_image, false);
imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
$color = imagecolortransparent($new_image, imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $color);

imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

$new_filename = str_replace('_retina.jpg', '.jpg', $filename);

imagejpeg($new_image, $new_filename);
```